# In Jekyll, is it possible to hide a page on production

Tags: jekyll

I want to know if it is possible to hide page(s) in Jekyll when pushed to production. For example, I have a page called `crazy-toes` that I'm currently developing. But have different edits/changes for other pages that need to be pushed live. Is there a way if someone types in their browser `mysite.com/crazy-toes/` they go to a 404? I know there is the `published` variable for the Front Matters, but for multiple pages, it doesn't seem efficient.

Answer (score 2):

You could store the page in [Drafts](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/posts/#drafts).